# specific page is blank

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website. The site is all working except for an article that I have recently created.

The article page : http://www.elkachef.net/?p=19328 is completely blank, it returns an http code zero

the website is working without a problem : http://www.elkachef.net/

What could be the issue and how can I fix it?

I have updated to the latest version, yet the page is still not displaying

Thank you for your help, I truly appreciate it.

Comment: never underestimate the value of server logs. That's the first place I'd check.

Comment: Post the contents of the page.  I was able to get to it once, but not twice. Also delete any cache you may have if using a cache plugin.

Comment: "This page isn’t working
www.elkachef.net didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" sounds  server related rather than your blog, did you change in serve settings?

Comment: thank you guys for the suggestions. I only have access to the wordpress administration. I will contact the site administrator to get the server log